# Django: __unicode__ | coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, OptionAttribute found

Tags: python, django, unicode, typeerror

I have those Models:

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, unique=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True,  blank=True)
    stock_level = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    weight = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=5)
    height = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=5)
    width = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=5 decimal_places=5)
    length = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=5)
    is_master = models.BooleanField()
    image_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='variations')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class OptionType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation, related_name='options')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class OptionAttribute(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    option_type = models.ForeignKey(OptionType)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.value


class Option(models.Model):
    option_attribute = models.ForeignKey(OptionAttribute)
    variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.option_attribute
```

Using the admin Page to enter Options Objects which is just a relation between 2 Models (Foreign Keys) Gives me an Error:

```
TypeError at /admin/backend/option/add/

coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, OptionAttribute found

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://192.168.100.10:5000/admin/backend/option/add/
Django Version:     1.8
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, OptionAttribute found

Exception Location:     /home/vagrant/python/Platform/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py in force_text, line 92
Python Executable:  /home/vagrant/python/Platform/venv/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/vagrant/python/Platform/webshaper',
 '/home/vagrant/python/Platform/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/vagrant/python/Platform/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/vagrant/python/Platform/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/vagrant/python/Platform/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/vagrant/python/Platform/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/vagrant/python/Platform/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/vagrant/python/Platform/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Fri, 31 Jul 2015 13:41:03 +0800
```

Traceback: http://dpaste.com/146YZP6

I have googled around for the same problems mostly the problem is caused by the **unicode** function as it can't return Null values. But solutions suggested for the problem didn't help.

Anyone has any idea what is causing this?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to rewrite unicode method at Option model to that: def __unicode__(self): return self.option_attribute.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need string or buffer, OptionAttribute found

This tells you, that your `__unicode__()` method returns something that is not a string or a buffer (or an unicode object).

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__unicode__):

> [ `__unicode__()` ... ] should return a Unicode object

You return an `OptionAttribute` object and python complains about this.

You probably want to replace

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.option_attribute
```

with

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.option_attribute)
```

Answer (score 0):

the Foreign  in **unicode** is will be a object.
if you want ge the foregin id . return str(self.option_attributes) will be ok